# eps to Adobe Illustrator. Color changes completely

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-conversion, eps

I have done a sort of brochure/book in flash, the printer needs ai.

Here is what i am doing. I am exporting the image as eps, and importing into AI

The problem is this:

The colors look different always on AI

If my AI document color mode is RGB, even if they look horrible, when exporting as pdf, they go back to normal or similar.

If my AI document color mode is CMYK, they colors look horrible and when exporting to pdf still look horrible.

The question is, what do i do to get this right for the printer? Will the colors look good in the CMYK (i read this is how it is supposed to be) in print, even if they look bad on the screen or the pdf? How am i supposed to solve this.

Please help

Comment: You have a Flash file which is RGB, you are importing this in to Illustrator and exporting that as a CMYK PDF where the colors are different. Have I got that right?

Comment: The answer to this **What do i do to get this right for the printer?** is do that on Ilustrator or Corel, InDesign or Scribus. Yes will be hacks and tricks, but to do it wright is to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this three color settings and play with them.

1. File > Document Color Mode (this will actually modify you document color)
2. View > Proof Colors [check/uncheck] (also try View > Poof Setup. This won't affect your actual file. It will only display a simulated color for your display.)
3. When exporting as PDF on the left panel go to "Output" and on the right options checkout the selected option from the dropdown menu "Color Conversion:"

I know this is not a good practice but some times I setup my printable PDF  as follows:
1. Select "Hi Quality Print" preset
2. Change the **Output > Color Conversion to : No Conversion**.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]